# Switch DEBUG doesn't seem to be working in my code

Tags: verilog

Following code I tried on EDA playground with command appended with +define+DEBUG  but DEBUG switch doesn't seem to be working. Its always block is sensitive to error and this variable is changing four times here but still the block is not being sensitive.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7Cg

```
module test;      
  integer error;
  event err;

  initial
  begin
      #10 ->err;
      #10 ->err;
      #3 ->err;
      #1 ->err;
      #10 finish(error);
      $display("%d",error);
  end

  initial error=0;

  always@(err)
  begin
      error=error+1;
  end

  always@(error)
  begin
    `ifdef DEBUG
      $display("Error at %d",$time);
    `endif
  end

  task finish(wrong);
    integer wrong;
  begin
    #10 if(wrong==0) $display("-----------TEST PASSED-----------");
        else $display("---------------TEST FAILED---------------");
  end
  endtask  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+define+DEBUG` is a compile time argument, not a run time. Moving `+define+DEBUG` to the appropriate line will fix the issue. See http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7ES

FYI: SystemVerilog has `$test$plusargs`/`$value$plusargs` which will allow run time arguments. Example with run time argument `+DEBUG`: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5zF

```
always@(err) begin
  error=error+1;
  if($test$plusargs("DEBUG")) begin
    $display("Error at %d",$time);
  end
end
```

Comment: I am interested to know some examples wherein how the compiler directives and defining text macros can be useful in verilog.